# AirPods on Galaxy S21 don't always connect even though they show connected

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

Usually taking an AirPod out of the case and putting it in my ear works fine - it connects to Bluetooth as per the indicator up top and audio works, but other times it shows as connected per the indicator but audio does not go to it.

I can fix it by turning off Bluetooth and then back on and choosing to connect to the AirPods, or sometimes by putting it back in the case and taking it back out.

Any thoughts on how to address the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Bluetooth isn't always reliable so you might want to "forget" the device on your phone and then pair it again to see if that resolves the issue.

You might also be able to see what is going on by [enabling Bluetooth Debugging on your phone](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging#bt-phone). After doing that and reproducing the issue you should have some logs that will either tell you the issue or give you more information to add to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the AirPods Pro 2 fixed the issue.

Perhaps it was a defect in the first model that didn't play nicely with Android.